# Nunit missing code coverage option in xml report

Tags: nunit, specflow, nunit-console

I am generating an NUnit test report XML from solution. I am using Specflow to generate an HTML file, however the report is missing code coverage summary.

Please help me to add code coverage summary in report.

I am using this batch file:

```
cd C:\TF_Test\Infrastructure_Tests\NUnit-2.6.3\NUnit-2.6.3\bin 
nunit-console.exe /labels /out=TestResult.txt /xml=TestResult.xml C:\TF_Test\Infrastructure_Tests\Infrstructure.1100_Tests\bin\Release\ThinkIQ.Platform.Infrastructure._1100.Tests.dll 
C:\TF_Test\Infrastructure_Tests\SpecFlow.1.9.0\tools\specflow.exe nunitexecutionreport C:\TF_Test\Infrastructure_Tests\Infrstructure.1100_Tests\Infrastructure._1100.Te‌​sts.csproj /out:C:\TF_Test\Infrastructure_Tests\Report1.xml
```

Comment: What command are you using?

Comment: This is batch file which I am using to generate. @echo off
cd C:\TF_Test\Infrastructure_Tests\NUnit-2.6.3\NUnit-2.6.3\bin 
nunit-console.exe /labels /out=TestResult.txt /xml=TestResult.xml C:\TF_Test\Infrastructure_Tests\Infrstructure.1100_Tests\bin\Release\ThinkIQ.Platform.Infrastructure._1100.Tests.dll

C:\TF_Test\Infrastructure_Tests\SpecFlow.1.9.0\tools\specflow.exe nunitexecutionreport C:\TF_Test\Infrastructure_Tests\Infrstructure.1100_Tests\Infrastructure._1100.Tests.csproj /out:C:\TF_Test\Infrastructure_Tests\Report1.xml

Comment: Does the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/10636560/3419534 help at all?

Comment: @ClickRick that question doesn't seem to be related to including code coverage in the XML results.